# Server-side Single sign-on with Live Connect API

Tags: php, rest, restful-authentication, outlook.com, live-connect-sdk

Assuming I get user's email and password in a variable, how do I authenticate on Live Connect on behalf of this user who consent to grant me with permissions to access his information ? 
Is it possible to perform this by only using REST implementation ?

Using PHP.

[EDIT]
I need to use my own login page (user/password) and cannot use the Outlook Live Connect SignIn window.

Comment: See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh243648.aspx)

Comment: Thanks SquareCat, have seen this already. It gives the API objects structure but does not explain how to sign in a user on his behald so I access his information. I looked to their [sample](https://github.com/liveservices/LiveSDK/tree/master/Samples/PHP/OauthSample) but still haven't find how to signin using email/password the user enter on my own web app login page.